# -ne is not working in Powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, logical-operators

I am not sure if I am missing something or overlooking something silly, but the script below is supposed to compare two strings and see if they are equal or not.

```powershell
if ($Previous_WAN_IP -ne $Current_WAN_IP) {

  if ($Previous_WAN_IP -eq "") {write-host "External IP Script is Ready";Exit}
  if ((@([Byte[]][char[]]$Current_WAN_IP -eq 46).Count)-ne 3) {write-host "No Valid IP Address Retrieved";Exit}

  Write-Host "IP Address Has Changed, Sending e-mail"
  $MessageBody = "External IP Address Has Changed"
  .\Scripts\SecureEmailScript.ps1
}
```

I have put a breakpoint on the if statement containing the `-ne`. Both of the values being compared are identical and are of type `System.String`. The issue is though that it will still enter the if statement... even though the values are equal. If I make the values not equal then it is the same result. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My first suspicion would be that one or the other has trailing whitespace.

Comment: You are correct! After I posted this I went and looked at the lengths of the strings... One is 14 and the other is 13. So I added <string>.trim to both of them and now one is 13 and the other is 12 haha... At least I know the issue.

Comment: @EBGreen Well it is working now although I am feeling pretty silly for not thinking of that from the beginning. Haha thanks for your help. If you want to make an answer and describe the Trim() process, I would be glad to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid trailing (or leading) spaces especially when doing string comparisons with the .Trim() string method. In your specific case:

```
if ($Previous_WAN_IP.Trim() -ne $Current_WAN_IP.Trim()){
```

Just be sure to do the Trim() somewhere in the code that does not execute repeatedly if possible to minimize the effect on run time.